# Flutter Access child function from its grand parent

Tags: flutter, dart

In my e-commerce admin cpanel app
I have a very big form (product form) with lots of section one for title and description and price, one for sale one for colors and seizes and images etc.
I divided it into smaller widget in separated classes and each of them has its own children widgets in another separated classes
each child class has a ( onSave ) function which I need to trigger from the main form button located in the grand grand parent so how can I access all ( onSave )  functions from this parent

In this ( onSave ) functions I'm using provider pattern to pass the data I collect in each widget to a provider class and in there I can send the datd to the server

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Form() widget and place your input fields in it as children. then you define a GlobalKey() and pass it to the form's key property. once you call the save method on the GlobalKey, all children widgets onSaved function will be called.

e.g.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Name"),
                      onSaved: (name) {
                        // do stuff
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Category"),
                      onSaved: (category) {
                        // do stuff
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _formKey.currentState.save();
              },
              child: Text("pressme"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ya I'm familiar with this approach, but what if the Form children are separated in different classes, in your example take each TextFormField and put it in a new stateLessWidget in  new textformfield.dart file, so know instead of having all children together in the same file  now each one of them exist in separated class (widget) and then imagine there are like 20 of them, how can I apply _formKey.currentState.save(); on all of them.